# При входящем звонке, выключать воспроизведение аудио, как?

Tags: java, android-studio, broadcast-receiver, action, android-broadcastreceiver

Использую такой код для проверки того, подключены наушники или нет, и собственно говоря, правильно реагировать на отключение наушников от телефона, и последующую остановку воспроизведения.

Можно ли здесь же дописать действия, при получении входящего вызова? Что бы воспроизведение тоже останавливалось?

```
private boolean headsetConnected = false;
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)){
                if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0){
                    headsetConnected = false;
                    if (HomeActivity.musicSrv.isPng()){
                        HomeActivity.musicSrv.pausePlayer();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники отключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (!headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1){
                    headsetConnected = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники подключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

использую жизненный цикл onResume. в onDestroy и onPause ничего не дописывал, чтобы работоспособность всего кода гарантировалась во всех активностях:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

в манифесте дописал:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".activity.HomeActivity$MusicIntentReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался уже), добавив класс :

```
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: HomeActivity.musicSrv.pausePlayer(); // здесь используем своё обращение к плееру
    Toast.makeText(context, "Входящий вызов", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

в методе onCreate, добавил:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

в onDestroy добавил:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
```